# What is the best way to get the viewport size in a Cycle.js app?

Tags: cyclejs

I'd like to create a stream that passes viewport size [height, width] event for a Cycle.js app using SnabDom and MostJS.  It looks like installing an insert hook on the :root div to get at the vDOM.elm properties should work, but so far no joy.  Also, once I get that, how would I go about exporting the events from inside the hook callback to the size$ stream?

I know there are quicker and easier ways to go about this by simply interrogating the Window object, but I'm trying to see how far I can get with pure FRP.

Comment: That form of question might be better suited for this community: https://gitter.im/cyclejs/cyclejs

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the Rect of your app container

```
DOM.select(':root')
.elements()
.map(x => x[0].getBoundingClientRect())
```

As per my knowledge, currently cycle doesn't provide access to viewport.